# GCP Composer - ftplib timeouterror errno 110 connection timed out

Tags: google-cloud-composer, ftplib

I trying to getting data from FTP server's txt file by GCP Composer Tasks.

So i imported and used ftplib package in code.

like this.

```
ftp = FTP()
ftp.connect(host=HOST,port=PORT, timeout=600)
ftp.login(user=USER,passwd=PSWD)
ftp.set_pasv(True)

ftp.sendcmd('TYPE A')
conn = ftp.transfercmd(F"RETR {PATH}")
fp = conn.makefile('rb')
```

but. this (`conn = ftp.transfercmd(F"RETR {PATH}")`) code made `TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out` Error.

```
ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1166, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1285, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1315, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 150, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 161, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/FTP_ZIPCODE_to_BQ_DAG.py", line 91, in replace_BQ_table
    conn = ftp.transfercmd(F"RETR {PATH}")
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 389, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 350, in ntransfercmd
    conn = socket.create_connection((host, port), self.timeout,
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Did you know reason????

and... this is my gcp composer evironments.

- Image Version : composer-1.17.7-airflow-2.1.4
- python version : 3
- Network VPC-native : Enable

Comment: Have you tried setting a longer [timeout](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/ftplib.html#:~:text=user%3D%27%27%2C%20passwd%3D%27%27%2C%20acct%3D%27%27%2C-,timeout%3DNone,-%2C%20source_address%3DNone%2C%20*%2C%20encoding)?  Also, Does the command work fine in the console?

Comment: Yes i tried. but Task finished before timeout. (i set 60*10*60sec)
`ftp.connect(host=HOST,port=PORT, timeout=60*10*60)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that can be happening is that the connection is not working. In order to get the connection working, you need to set up Cloud NAT together with Cloud Composer to give the workers public internet access, as described in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/private-ip-environments#public_internet_access_for_your_workflows).